# Is it possible to see if a branch has been deleted in a remote repo?

Tags: git

A pipeline that I am working on has a common failure of not being able to find a branch in the upstream origin. This happens for two reasons, either the branch has been merged and deleted before the pipeline has finished running or the branch never existed in the first place.

I know `git ls-remote --heads <repo>`  displays all currently opened branches on a remote repo, but I need to see deleted branches and the only information I have is the branch name. Is it possible to do this without the use of the gh cli?

Comment: Do you have a local clone of the remote repo? If so, you could use `git log --all --merges --grep=BRANCHNAME` to see if the branch name was mentioned in any merge.

Comment: No unfortunately it is not stored locally

Comment: Maybe you could accomplish (whatever you're doing) using the commit ID instead of the branch name. Presumably the commit ID will still be there even if the branch is deleted.